# collecting locality in Italian

Tags: vocabulary

I am trying to translate "collecting locality" into Italian language.

It is a place in nature where is e.g. gold, silver, or some mineral etc. and people are there to get it.

suggestions: raccolta di località, miniera, Sito di scavo

Thank you.

Comment: *Raccolta di località* does not make sense in Italian, *sito di scavo* reminds me archaeological excavations, *miniera* is good for gold and silver.

Comment: ...and coal, and most solid minerals found underground, while an open air “collecting locality” (say, for marble and other stones) is a *cava* (plural *cave*, not to be confused with an English “cave”, which is a *caverna* or a *grotta* in Italian).

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the activities described here: "[Mineral collecting](http://www.minsocam.org/MSA/collectors_corner/MineralCollecting.htm)", I think that we would probably refer to them as "***[giacimenti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=giacimento) minerari".***

Garzanti

Note that this activity  is not that popular in Italy as far as I know.

Comment: Small nuance of meaning: an ore location is a *giacimento* whether you use it or not, whereas *collecting locality* implies that it is actively mined.

Comment: @Federico Poloni - do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Actually I think that @Gio answer is well suited given the context

Comment: @Gio No, I don't. *Miniera* (already suggested in OP's question) is the best I can come up with.

Comment: The very definition cited by Gio («accumulo naturale nella crosta terrestre di minerali, idrocarburi e fossili, che si possono sfruttare economicamente») mentions *natural* deposits of minerals etc. that *may* be exploited, not sites where they are actually collected.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word "*giacimento*" (for example for oil, gas, etc.) or "*miniera*" if this place is inside a cave for iron, silver, gold or other not fluid materials. 
Also *impianto di estrazione* could be acceptable, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Is this "collecting locality" in the context of an industrial or hobbyist activity?

If it's the former, "giacimento" feels like the best translation.
(or you could use something like "area di estrazione" if you want to stress out that the site is currently actively exploited).

If it's the latter, a rapid google survey of sites dedicated to mineral collectors and geology enthusiasts seems to suggest the use of "area mineralogica", "sito mineralogico", or "località mineralogica" to indicate places of interest.

Other relevant general terms are "miniera" for "mine", "cava" for "quarry", "vena" or "filone" for "vein" or "lode".